# Running a GTK+ application on a Linux machine, from Windows

Tags: gtk, x11

I have Installed GTK on a Linux machine.
I am connecting To Linux Machine from a Telnet Session to compile the GTK programs
From A Windows Machine. I am using Cygwin on Windows Machine. but i am not able to see 
GUI output of my GTK program on my Windows Machine.

When i run program from my terminal i get this error:

```
(helloworld:22576): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I tried solutions from every answer posted, but no use now i am getting following error:

```
$ ./helloworld
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
(helloworld:22710): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 172.25.0.161:0
```

and i am getting following error on my Cygwin console:

```
client 6 rejected from IP 172.25.0.91 Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: -1
```

Comment: Is Google down again? Sad day. :(

Comment: This is very confusing. Please explain clearly what you want to do. Do you want to run a GTK program on Windows via Cygwin? What does that Linux machine have to do with it?

Comment: I tried every answer but no use now i am getting following Error.

$ ./helloworld
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
(helloworld:22710): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 172.25.0.161:0

Comment: Bombe -- I think every one should ask you before posting a question.
Why don't you just keep away from the questions that don't relate to you!.... No one had requested you to comment or post on this question so just keep distance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the DISPLAY variable in your telnet session to the IP address or DNS name of your Windows machine and append ":0"

```
export DISPLAY=windows.your.domain:0
```

And you must start an X server on the Windows machine (comes with Cygwin but you must start it).

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the [X window system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin/X) (install with Cygwin) on your Windows-box and enable remote connections (probably with [xhost](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xhost.1.html)). Set the DISPLAY-variable on your Linux-box to the address of your Windows-box and :0, as such:

```
export DISPLAY=192.168.1.123:0
```

---

I can recommend using [ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) rather than telnet, for security reasons. In this case you do not need to enable remote connections with xhost, and you do not need to set the DISPLAY-variable. You only need to enable [X forwarding](http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should install X-server on your windows machine and make sure you have DISPLAY set to `yourmachine:0` or something like that. Or better yet use ssh instead of telnet (e.g. putty) and tunnel your X connection. You'll have to do a bit on your own research, though, because the complete answer would be a lengthy one.

Answer (score 1):

Install an small X server on Windows [XMing32](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/), then run it, use [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) as a console client, and check "X11 Forwarding" in Connection->SSH->X11.

*Unfortunately*, X11 Forwarding is not available through Telnet, you must run a SSH server on the target Linux and connect through SSH. (See if `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` requires enabling X11 Forwarding too).

Comment: thanks i forgot to set X11 Forwarding flag to true.
I worked!